# Many different UITableViewCells in one TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have an `NSDictionary` that we will say is like this:

```
key:       value:
name       Bookshelf
movies     Array containing: (Movie 1, Movie 2, Movie 3)
books      Array containing: (Book 1, Book 2, Book 3)
music      Array containing: (Music 1, Music 2, Music 3)
```

And so on. Now what I'm trying to do is create a tableView that displays all this information, but with different types of cells based on what the dictionary key is. For example, movies use `cellForMovies` books use `cellForBooks` music use `cellForMusic`, each has it's own layout.

Obviously, I am oversimplifying, but hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do.

I am able to accomplish this if I do sections and a different cell type for each section, but I don't want to do that.  I want to be able to have a table like this, for example:

```
cellForBooks
cellForMovies
cellForMovies
cellForMusic
cellForBooks
```

and so on...Any ideas or resources you can point me to? I only care about iOS 5 support (storyboards).

**Edit with solution:**

A big thank you to everyone who helped, especially atticus who put the final piece together.

What ended up working was to change the structure of the data to be an array of dictionaries and then add a `Key: type Value: book/movie/music` to each entry. The data structure now looks like:

```
Array[0]: Dictionary: [Key: type Value: book], [Key: name Value: Physics];
Array[1]: Dictionary: [Key: type Value: music], [Key: name Value: Rock];
```

Then to configure the cells I did this:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSDictionary *object = [self.listOfStuff objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"book"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"BookCell";
}else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"music"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"MusicCell";
}else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"movie"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"MovieCell";
}
```

each of these had a different tableviewcell in the storyboard. We figured out if you want to use any of the built-in cell features, like `cell.textLabel.text` you needed to do this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Is there a storyboard somewhere? I don't see one in the repository.

Comment: It got localized for some reason. It is in the en.lprog directory.

Comment: Got it. Everything's fine, except you're using the built-in textLabel property on the custom cell. When you set it, the cell un-hides it and the label's background color is solid white. When you select the cell, it temporarily makes the background clear, and you can see the items behind it. If you want to use the built-in textLabel that's fine, just set the background color to clear:      `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;`

Comment: I want to know how to display "Movie 1" value in "MovieCell"; Please help me because i am searching last two days.

Comment: @Jasper you can have a customized cell for each `CellIdentifier`, in this case the `MovieCell`. You would just want to create something like a label and set the text to be the name of Movie1 once it's loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A big thank you to everyone who helped, especially atticus who put the final piece together.

What ended up working was to change the structure of the data to be an array of dictionaries and then add a `Key: type Value: book/movie/music` to each entry. The data structure now looks like:

```
Array[0]: Dictionary: [Key: type Value: book], [Key: name Value: Physics];
Array[1]: Dictionary: [Key: type Value: music], [Key: name Value: Rock];
```

Then to configure the cells I did this:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSDictionary *object = [self.listOfStuff objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"book"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"BookCell";
}else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"music"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"MusicCell";
}else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"movie"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"MovieCell";
}
```

each of these had a different tableviewcell in the storyboard. We figured out if you want to use any of the built-in cell features, like `cell.textLabel.text` you needed to do this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 6):

In your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method you can return many types of cells according to `indexPath`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row > 5) { // Your conditions here to choose between Books and Movies
        BookCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bookCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"bookCell"];
        }
        return cell;
    } else {
        MovieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"movieCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"movieCell"];
        }
        return cell;
    }
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Under iOS 5 with storyboards you don't need to perform the check for a nil cell and instantiate anymore. -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will take care of that for you.

Comment: If you return nil from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, your app will crash. You should return something at the end. In your case, you never get past the if/else so it's okay, but something to watch out for.

Comment: You can use some typecasting to avoid returning `nil`.
As for your first comment, you can use storyboards, but it doesn't mean you can't instantiate a UITableView in code, or subclass UITableViewController. So checking for `nil` after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` might be useful, since `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` still can return `nil`

Comment: I was just referring to your last "return nil" statement which in this case is actually redundant anyway. If you ever did "return nil" there, the app would crash.

Comment: It certainly doesn't hurt to throw in the extra checks, but the question specifically mentioned that he only cared about storyboard support, and so leaving those out is fine too.

Answer (score 3):

In your storyboard, set your tableView to use Dynamic Prototypes. Then, create a cell for each kind of cell you're going to use. Customize those appropriately, and then give each one a unique Reuse Identifier in the inspector (e.g. MovieCell).

Then, in your tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, determine the appropriate kind of cell for the content at that index path. If the cell at indexPath should be a movie cell, you would create the cell using:

```
static NSString * MovieCellIdentifier = @"MovieCell"; // This must match the storyboard
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MovieCellIdentifier];
```

That will give you the cell you specified as "MovieCell" in your storyboard. If you need to customize it further, create a UITableViewCell subclass and specify that for the cell in Storyboard. Then, you can refer to the properties etc. here for customization by casting the returned cell:

```
MovieTableViewCell *movieCell = (MovieTableViewCell *)cell;
// customize
```

Comment: One question: at the end of cellForRowAtIndexPath function, which cell will be return? Coz you've got many customized Tableviewcell, e.g. MovieTableViewCell, BookTableViewCell... How will you return them at the end?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you should implement all your cell types in one cell. Which means you should have one `UITableViewCell` class and .xib for all of them. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, create the cell, then depending on the actual requirement, show/hide the subviews that makes up a book or a movie.

In such design, your cell will be somewhat heavyweight. However, it's still better than using several cell classes because this way cell reusing is more efficient (`[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier]`).

I believe UITableView is designed towards one type of cell. So if your layout varies, you can still put them in one place and use frame or show/hide to control cell behavior.

Comment: Using storyboards, it's fine to create multiple cell types, and makes the code much more readable.

Comment: I agree @atticus. I tried this method and it makes the scrolling a bit lagged cause there are a lot of subviews recycling. I ended up recreating my classes. Having a lot of classes recycling at the cellForRowAtIndexPath makes the table scrolling more smooth and faster.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should use the following as your cell identifier.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tmpTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *cellIdentifier            =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell               =   [tmpTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
if (nil == cell) {
    cell    =   [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

// do ur stuff here

}
return cell;
}
```